# What would make the <a> to not create a link

Tags: html, anchor

I am updating a website that I didn't create, this has been a bit of a chore.  There is an instance where links to other parts of the site have been used and they aren't working.  I have studied the code and can't seem to figure out why the link isn't appearing ... please help

This is the code snippet ...

```
<article class="grid_4 maxheight">
    <div class="box1 maxheight">
        <div class="box-indent">
            <h3><strong>01.</strong>Projects</h3>
                Lorem Ipsem sit dolor ... 
        </div>
  <div class="aligncenter"><a href="contacts.php" class="box-link">Suggest</a>    </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

this code is repeated for 3 separate boxes and none of the anchor tags are creating a link at all, nothing ... doesn't even exist I don't know what is causing this to not work, all the other links on the page seem to work just not these 3

Comment: Code seem ok, you have to use browser inspector and see if there is any `display: none` rule applied.

Comment: it is better you share the link of this page so that we can check and give you the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give Full path of contacts.php in `href` attribute in anchor `<a></a>` tag.
Or make the contacts.php saved in same folder then It will links to the corresponding page.

If link and data in `<a>anchor tag</a>` is invisible then check css property of that class/id and make `display: block` for that css.
It is working for mine.

Comment: Thank you for the response ... contact.php is in same folder ... I checked css for that class it's set to display: inline-block;  I changed it to just block, all it did was make it look funny ... but it's still not working - the code appears to be correct, could something else be causing it to misbehave?

Comment: can we have your css styles for above elements.

Comment: just check inspect element and if errors are there, modify them there itself.  use F12 in browser to get this.

Comment: .box1 {
 background:url(../images/box1-bg.gif) left top no-repeat #4ebcc3;
 position:relative;
}
 .box1 h3 strong {
  color:#83d2d7;
 }
  .box1 .box-link {
   color:#4ebcc3;
  }.box-link {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px 20px 6px 20px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  font-size:23px;
  line-height:1.2307em;
  font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  border-radius:18px;
  -moz-border-radius:18px;
  -webkit-border-radius:18px;
  margin-bottom:28px;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  .box-link:hover {
   background:#f1f5f4;
   text-decoration:none;
  }

Comment: the page is www.planetcharities.org

Comment: Its working fine and has a good look and its linking too... remove the class slider for that div, it will solve your issue. is your problem solved? Great Site. Keep Going...